# How to switch Google accounts on Google Glass?

Tags: google-glass

I'm trying to develop for Google Glass. However I can't pair Google Glass with any of my devices (my Windows 7 laptop, my Kyocera Event Android mobile phone, and my iPhone 4S). I suspect that the problem is due to the Google Account used in the Glass is different compared to the Google Accounr I use in my other devices. However, I don't know if it is even possible to log out/switch Google account on Google glass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that is the problem, but it is possible.

There is no way to switch accounts on Glass. I would suggest you make sure any pictures you have on Glass are backed up, do a system reset, and initialize it with the account used on one of the other devices.

See https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3297404?hl=en for details